# Programatically change some words' color in an UITextView

Tags: ios, swift

So I have an UITextView with some text and I want everytime the user inputs, for example, the word "while", after it has been written it should change into purple. Also, I have another UITextView just to display content, no user interaction enabled, and I want that everytime the view appears, all the "while" words to also be purple. How do I do this? Can you help me, please? Thank you!

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
let initialText = textView.text!
let string_to_color = "while"
let range = (initialText as NSString).range(of: string_to_color)
let attribute = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: initialText)
attribute.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.purple, range: range)
textView.attributedText = attribute
```

But it colors only the first word. This is for the user interaction disabled text field. I haven't figured out how to do it for the text field that contains the words that the user inputs.

Comment: Not me, but you don't show any code or what you have tried already. Look up the `attributedText` property of `UITextView`.

Comment: probably because your question isn't very good.  All you have done is ask for someone to write some code for you, not to solve a specific problem.  

You don't show any code, or explain what you have tried, and what is going wrong. 

Try reading this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not getting the range correctly, here is an example of using attributed strings in Swift 3.0:

```
// get initial text as a String type (you will get this from your textview)
let initialText = "Swift Attributed String"

// create an attribute for the text color, I chose blue color
let myAttribute = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue ]

// create the attributed string and add the blue color attribute
let myString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: initialText, attributes: myAttribute )

// range starting at location 6 with a lenth of 10: "Attributed"
var myRange = NSRange(location: 6, length: 10) 

// OR get range of specific string in initialText
let newRange = (initialText as NSString).range(of: "Attributed")

// change the range of the word "Attributed" to have red text color
myString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: newRange)

// create another attribute for highlighting
let anotherAttribute = [ NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.yellow ]
// set the range of the "Attributed" part of the string to a yellow highlight
myString.addAttributes(anotherAttribute, range: newRange)
```

You can use this strategy to do whatever formatting you need to do with your string.  Just make sure that the range that you are getting is correct.

Comment: Thank you! And how should I set it so when the user types a specific word it immediately changes to that color?

Comment: I think that could be either tricky or easy, depending on what you need.

If the word purple is just the letters 'purple' anywhere on screen, then all you have to do whenever the text changes, find all instances of 'purple' and change the colour.

If you only want discrete words, then you have to check for 'purple' with a whole range of non-letter characters on either side - start / end of textview, space, comma, etc.,

Comment: I updated the code to show how to get the range based on a specific string in your original string

Comment: Sorry, but it still changes the color of the first searched word only.

Comment: `let initialText = textView.text!;
        let myAttribute = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black];
        let myString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: initialText, attributes: myAttribute);
        let newRange = (initialText as NSString).range(of: "is");
        myString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.purple, range: newRange);
        textView.attributedText = myString;
`

Comment: That code you posted works... when I try it on a string with the word "is" in it, the word "is" becomes purple and the rest of the text is black

Comment: But if the string contains more than one "is" it colors just the first one.

Comment: Why does it behave like this?